# document is undefined when require JQuery in a preload script (Electron BrowserWindow)

Tags: jquery, node.js, electron

I found a workaround but I don't understand the problem with `document` in `process.once('loaded')`

## Error on `require('jquery')`

In an electron [Browserwindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) (with `webPreferences.nodeIntegration = true`), I load JQuery with `<script>window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');</script>`.

I would rather avoid using `nodeIntegration` and define all the `require` in a preload script instead :

```js
process.once('loaded', () => {
  console.log('document', document);
  global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
});
```

The problem is that the `require` throws an error :

> Unable to load preload script: {hiddenPath}\app\windows\main\preload.js

This error hide :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
>       at assert ({hiddenPath}\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.js:899:20)

I went to check the file (jquery.js on line 899) and it's `var el = document.createElement("fieldset");`. The error say that `document` is undefined but the `console.log` just above display it...
**Why do the jquery.js don't know `document` ??**

### Solution/workaround I found

Require JQuery (and then bootstrap if you need it) in `window.onload`

```js
window.onload = function () {
  window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
  window.Bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
  console.log('JQuery and Bootstrap are loaded');
}

process.once('loaded', () => {
  global.ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
});
```

## Then I had "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

I load multiple JS scripts that need JQuery to work and also a "main file" (`init.js`) that calls each "boot" function.

The `head` tag (pug file) :

```
head
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')

  script(src='./clientJS/anotherScript.js')
  script(src='./clientJS/rpc.js')
  script(src='./clientJS/init.js')
```

**init.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  initAnother(); // in 'anotherScript.js'
  initRPC();     // in 'rpc.js'
  /* some others, hidden for brevity */
});
```

Here are the console logs :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at init.js:1
>
> JQuery and Bootstrap are loaded
>
> $('#btnSubmit') // I do that manually in the console and it find the button : so JQuery works

It seems that `init.js` is loaded before `window.onload` in the preload script

### Solution/workaround I found :

Mmove `$(document).ready()` in the preload script :

```js
window.onload = function () {
  window.jQuery = window.$ = require('jquery');
  window.Bootstrap = require('bootstrap') // ==> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined at bootstrap.bundle.min.js:6
  console.log('JQuery and Bootstrap are loaded');
  $(document).ready(function () {
    initAnother();
    initRPC();
  });
}
```

It's not a problem, just a detail but : **is there an other event like `window.onload` that is trigger just before to make JQuery loading first ?** I tried `window.onloadstart` but that doesn't works

## My final code:

**./main.js**

```js
'use strict'

const { app } = require('electron');
const setupPug = require('electron-pug');

const main = require('./windows/main');

async function Init() {
  try {
    let pug = await setupPug({pretty: true});
    pug.on('error', err => console.error('electron-pug error', err));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('can not initiate pug', err);
  }

  main.Create();
}

app.on('ready', Init);

/* hidden for brevity */
```

**./windows/main/index.js**

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

let win = null;

function Create() {
  if(win) return;

  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, './preload.js'),
    },
  });

  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/view.pug`);
  /* hidden for brevity */
}

module.exports = {
  Create,
}
```

Comment: all you're doing with jquery is saving it to the window. why can't the site you're loading do that

Comment: It's not really a web site, it's an Electron [BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) (I edited my post) an I need to move my `[...] = require('jquery')` from my pug file to a preload script to prevent using the `nodeIntegration = true` option

Comment: I meant that your browserwindow should be loading a page right? the preload script is intended for cases where your window needs to load third party content. if you're not doing that, you don't really need a preload

Comment: If I understood you, JQuery can not be `require` in the preload script because JQuery is not "really" a NodeJS module so I must import it in the pug/html file ? You have right, my preload script load some other nodeJS libs on the window (like `ipcRenderer`, `pug`, ...) and they work fine. Now I import with `script` and I edited my question because there are a few things I don't understand

Comment: well no, that wasn't really my point.all you're doing with jquery is sticking it on the window object, so it can be used in the page that you're loading in your window. why is that necessary? why can't that page load jquery? do you have control over it? Is your BrowserWindow actually loading any website, or file? do you have any `loadURL`, or `loadFile` calls?

Comment: My BrowserWindow loads a `pug` file with `loadURL`. I found a solution (or maybe it's just a workaround ?) :
now in the preload script I require JQuery and Bootstrap in `window.onload` and no more in `process.once('loaded')` as the [electron documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/process#event-loaded) shows...
And it works. I updated my question to explain it and ask if this is the right way.